# get formated date based on the different culture setting

Tags: javascript, date, globalization

I have use the following code snippet to localize the date object.

```
var dateObject = Globalize.format(new Date(), "dd/MM/yyyy", "it-IT");
```

in this case I have tried to get the italian format. But I got the following exception

> Unable to get property 'calendar' of undefined or null reference

How to the formatted date?

Note: while using en-US instead of italian it works fine

Comment: I highly recommend moment-js for your date-time formatting needs. http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just `it` instead of `it-IT`.  That is the actual language code for Italian.

The reference I use for language codes:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533052(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Provided link i can't see italian culture setting as it  and also i have tried with it instead of it-IT but i got the same exception

Comment: Try this: `Globalize.locale( "it-IT" );
console.log( Globalize.locale().attributes );`  And see what it returns.

Comment: Can you link to the Globalize library you're using?  The one I'm familiar with has that method.